# coldfusion left join not returning expected results

Tags: orm, coldfusion, hql, left-join

I am working on a left join query and i am not getting back my expected results. I have searched over and over and have not been able to find what is causing this issue. When i execute the following code it returns the results of a LEFT INNER JOIN(only records from the left that match an item in the right). I have tried to specify LEFT OUTER with no success. Am i missing something simple?

```
var records = ORMExecuteQuery("SELECT new map(inst.id AS installationId,
                                                inst AS installation,
                                                uaa.id AS id,
                                                uaa.permission AS permission,
                                                uaa.app AS app)
                                            FROM Installation AS inst, 
                                                LEFT JOIN inst.userApplicationAccesses AS uaa
                                                    WITH uaa.user.userId = ?", [Arguments.userId]);
```

Comment: I am assuming that your left inner join is just an inner join.

Comment: yeah, sorry. been trying to figure it out for the last day and a half so "left" is imbedded in my brain right now

Comment: huh, looks like it does exist, just doesn't seem something you would want to use though.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389204/left-inner-join-vs-left-outer-join-why-does-the-outer-take-longer

Answer (score 0):

ok your left join is wierd.  You are left joining to a column, not a table, and that column is part of your first table (you are even referncing the as name).

You outer join should look something like:

```
Select *
From Table_A as A
Left Outer Join Table_B as B on B.ID = A.ID
```

and yes, both Table_A and Table_B can be the same table, but that table should be listed out twice.

Comment: doing a simple select all wont work. i need to map them to specific properties. Also with HQL there is no "on" statement.

Comment: I don't expect you to do a selct all ( i would yell at you if you did) It is just there to help show the proper full syntax of an outer join query

Comment: ive got the proper SQL syntax that does what i need, but im having troubles converting that to HQL
`SELECT Installation.id AS installationId,
 userApplicationAccess.id AS id,
 userApplicationAccess.permission AS permission,
 userApplicationAccess.appId AS app
FROM Installation
 LEFT JOIN userApplicationAccess
  ON userApplicationAccess.installationId = Installation.id
  and userApplicationAccess.userId = 191
order by installationId`

Comment: sadly, I don't know HQL, but what response are you getting?  It is an error? or just bad data?

Comment: instead of returning multiple records it only returns 1 or 2